# Why is my section element not showing up when I put in my canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, z-index

Whenever I put in a `<canvas id=c></canvas>`, my `<section id="greeter"></section>` does not show up on the page. I've played with z-index and moved the canvas outside of the body, and it doesn't make a difference. Also, my canvas is not covering the whole page. When I scroll down the canvas moves with the body, but only covers the window of my screen at the beginning. When you scroll down there is a blank background.

[html&css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p6Ww.png)

Comment: Please put your markup & styles here in your question. Don't include the entire document, but just what's relevant.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add HTML AND CSS Code instead of code image ? Thanks :)

Comment: If you want the canvas to stay at the top of the screen no matter how far down the page you scroll, you should consider using: `position:sticky;`   But if you want the canvas to always cover the entire screen, how are you going to display anything else?  Is the canvas to be used as a background image?

Comment: And, @isherwood etc are right - an image of your code is all well and good, but if we want to replicate what you have done, we have to retype the whole thing ourselves.  Always post enough javascript, html and css to allow us to copy/paste all that we need to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using `margin: 0;` to example in your css example `*{margin= 0;}` because most browsers allocate margins to element if null.

Comment: or maybe it is because you place the id as `<canvas id=c></canvas>` which should have been `<canvas id="c"></canvas>` but in most cases it still works in some browsers.

Comment: Interestingly enough quotes aren't required if there is only a single value in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It does "show up".  You just can't see it because it is now behind the black rectangle of the canvas or because the font colour is also black.  Change the canvas styles to:

```css
canvas {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:black;
  z-index:-1;
}

.greeting {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<section class="greeting">
  <h1>Billiam Robert</h1>
  <p>Junior Software Developer</p>
</section>
```

And, now you see it.  Using absolute positioning has taken the canvas out of the normal flow of the page and shifted the section tag up.  Setting the z-index should move the canvas into the background - but you would still only see your text if the colour of the text was not black.

(edited to use a snippet)